# How to scrap content of this 'p' tag here inside 'div' of a class in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the word of the day and its meaning using python, but I suck at web scrapping and I'm struggling a lot with scrapping texts. I wrote a code but it prints nothing and I don't know why.

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I want to get the highlighted text.
The code I wrote is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = requests.get('https://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/today/japanese.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')
content =soup.find_all('div',class_='wotdr-item wotdr-item--translation js-col-item')
for i in content:
   for p in i.find_all('p'):
       print(p.text)
```

But this doesn't print anything. Can somebody tell my mistakes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you want to receive is dynamic. It is generated during page loading. Initially, you need to look at the requests that the page creates and find the right one.

```
    import requests
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    
    url = 'https://wotd.transparent.com/rss/ja-widget.xml'
    response = requests.get(url)
    root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
    print('Japanese word:', root.find('words/word').text)
    print('English translation:', root.find('words/translation').text)
    print('Part of speech:', root.find('words/wordtype').text)
    print('Japanese example:', root.find('words/fnphrase').text)
    print('English example:', root.find('words/enphrase').text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Japanese word: 警報
English translation: alarm, alert, warning, warning signal
Part of speech: noun
Japanese example: 台風警報に気を付けなければいけません。
English example: You must pay attention if you see any typhoon warnings.
```

**UPDATE**

```
for wotd in root.findall('words'):
    print('Yomigana:',wotd.find('{http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/}transliteratedWord').text)
    print('Yomigana example:', wotd.find('{http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/}transliteratedSentence').text)
```

OR:

```
print('Yomigana:', root.find('words/{http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/}transliteratedWord').text)
print('Yomigana example:', root.find('words/{http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/}transliteratedSentence').text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Yomigana: けいほう
Yomigana example: たいほうけいほうにきをつけなければいけません。
```

Comment: Yeah it works, Thanks ! But similarly, when I try to run print(root.find('words/wotd:transliteratedWord').text) it shows error, why ?

Comment: @Trickster i updated my answer. This keys in namespace, so you need specified full path, or `namespaces = {'wotd': 'http://www.transparent.com/word-of-the-day/'}`